# As a small business about to overhaul infrastructure and go virtual, how can we take advantage of all the features of the QNAP TS-439 Pro II+?

Tags: virtualization, network-attached-storage, iscsi, lun

Specifically, how can we benefit from these current list of features?  We're very new to this and I want to be able to talk intelligently to our IT consultant.
VMware Ready
Citrix Ready
Built-in iSCSI target service
Virtual Disk Drive (via iSCSI Initiator)
Remote Replication
Multi-LUN per Target 
LUN Mapping & LUN Masking Support
SPC-3 Persistent Reservation Support

What other products should we compare this QNAP to?  I appreciate how informative the site is, but they only seem to sell their products through a small number of channels.  Is QNAP well known?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's a pretty low-end box, 'pro-sumer' as it were, presumably you want a NAS box like this because you want to use vMotion or similar? if you're not I'd very strongly suggest you spend the money on local/DAS disks, they'll be SO much faster. If you're using ESX/i then you can use this with either NFS or iSCSI - both will be pretty comparable performance-wise at this level. QNAP are vaguely well known for this end of the market, it's actually very similar to Thecus's 5200pro that I used to use at home to store my DVD rips, it was ideal for that until someone gave me something bigger.

Comment: Thank you.  General utility, but yes vMotion and ESX/i were mentioned, and also storing backup images to replicate offsite.  Does the NAS need to be able to do both NFS and iSCSI or you pick one or the other?  Would you recommend Thecus over QNAP?

Comment: Also, is NAS better for than DAS for offsite backup relay?

Comment: ^NAS better than DAS

Comment: Well if you want vMotion then you need FC/iSCSI or NFS but that's not a very good quality box to be honest, no dual controllers or even PSUs -I think it's fine for home use but I'd be constantly worried about it. Ironically it'd be fine for local backups that someone could rsync or whatever off to another site. Oh and either NFS or iSCSI, not both. I have no real feeling for either the Thecus or this box other than I think they're both not really professional quality. DAS is literally local storage so can't be remote or used for vMotion, though it's fast and cheap.